# VBA Excel : Row methods aren't working

Tags: vba, excel, debugging, runtime-error, excel-2007

Whenever I try to use a row method, there's the error 438 : Object doesn't support this property or method. For exemple:

```
With wb1.Sheets(3)
     If .Cells(k, 4) = "OK" And .Cells(k, 7) = "OK" And .Cells(k, 10) = "OK" Then .Row(k).EntireRow.Hidden = True ...
'or
WorkSheet1.Rows(Row1).Copy WorkSheet2.Rows(Row2)
```

I use Excel 2007. I don't know where went wrong. It seems to work fine for others.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the if-condition replace `row` with `rows`.
The second should work (assuming Worksheet1 and WorkSheet2 are valid worksheet-objects and Row1 and Row2 are integers).

Comment: @JanB Exactly. Thank you;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
.Rows(k).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

and for this to work 'WorkSheet1.Rows(Row1).Copy WorkSheet2.Rows(Row2)' try following

```
worksheets(1).rows(2).copy destination:= worksheets(2).rows(2)
```